# datetimepicker an unexpected error

Tags: date

I have used the following code for date time picker but not working it is not considering datetimepicker as a function.......all the files have been uploaded and used correctly for one page it is working fine and for the other it is not working can any one tell where the problem is???

```
var addrLoad = true;
  var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
  j$(document).focusin(function() {
     j$('.needsDatePicker').datetimepicker({
      timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    }).removeClass('needsDatePicker');
  });
```